# Emacs: how to start Gnus without fetching mail?

Tags: email, emacs, rss

When you run <kbd>M-x gnus</kbd> it first fetches all mail and news and only then opens group list. I want it to start without downloading mail, just open the group list right away. I skimmed through info manual, tried different commands starting with `gnus-`, scroogled - found nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

start gnus with unplugged.

`(setq gnus-plugged nil)`

you might want to read about [gnus Agent](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/gnus/Agent-Basics.html)

Quick hint: `J j` to toggle gnus plugging.

Comment: `gnus-no-server` worked too for me.